# SAGE How do I find e in this equation using sagemath?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, sage

The question asks us to solve for x in the given equation c' = x^e mod N, given the fact that we already know c', e , mod N. I looked into my tutorial, bu they only gave us a way to get e, but not for x.

I have manually tried to solve it and got the equation:

log c' = e log x mod N

but I don't know how to put in in Sage Math.

This is from the tutorial to find e:

discrete_log (c',Mod(x,N))

Answer (score 0):

The question is really asking how to find an e-th root of c' modulo N.

Say for example one wants to solve 12 = x^99 modulo 347.

This amounts to finding a 99-th root of 12 modulo 347.

Just set up the ring of integers modulo 347,

```
sage: A = Zmod(347)
sage: A
Ring of integers modulo 347
```

give a name to the element 12 in that ring,

```
sage: a = A(12)
```

and ask Sage for a 99-th root of this element:

```
sage: a.nth_root(99)
241
```

Check that this answers the question:

```
sage: A(241)^99
12

sage: pow(241, 99, 347)
12

sage: power_mod(241, 99, 347)
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Samuel's answer is far more comprehensive than this, but if you are looking for a really quick fix, you could use this (naive) function for small moduli:

```
sage: solve_mod(x^99==12, 347)
[(241,)]
```